# Error retrieving Avro schema Schema not found error code 40403

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have the below config of kafka

[image]

I tried to get the subject by version and i get like below

```
curl -u reader:reader -s "https://schema-registry1:8081/subjects/add_bank_account/versions/1/" | jq
{
  "subject": "add_bank_account",
  "version": 1,
  "id": 46,
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"CreateBankAccount\",\"namespace\":\"com.test.serviceprovider.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"exerciceFrameworkId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"agreementFileId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"conventionCode\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
}
```

I generate the `CreateBankAccount` using the plugin `avro-maven-plugin`

```
CreateBankAccount createBankAccount = CreateBankAccount.newBuilder()
    .setExerciceFrameworkId(event.exerciceFrameworkId)
    .setAgreementFileId(event.agreementFileId)
    .setConventionCode(convention.getConventionCode()).build();
```

Then i pushed a message to the topic with a string key and an avro serialized payload, but i have an error

```
MessageChannel messageChannel = kafkaStreams.addBankAccount();
messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(createBankAccount)
   .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build());
```

**Tracetrack:**

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
> Error retrieving Avro schema:
> {"type":"record","name":"CreateBankAccount","namespace":"com.test.serviceprovider.avro","fields":[{"name":"exerciceFrameworkId","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}},{"name":"agreementFileId","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}},{"name":"conventionCode","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}}]}
> Caused by:
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
> Schema not found; error code: 40403   at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:437)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:424)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:243)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:389)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:89)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:60)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:894)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:856)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:592)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:404)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:241)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:410)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:177)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1035)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:177)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
> at
> com.test.entities.handlers.ConventionEntityManager.on(ConventionEntityManager.java:168)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedMessageHandlingMember.handle(AnnotatedMessageHandlingMember.java:144)
> at
> org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedHandlerInspector$NoMoreInterceptors.handle(AnnotatedHandlerInspector.java:372)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter.java:94)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.SimpleEventHandlerInvoker.handle(SimpleEventHandlerInvoker.java:112)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.MultiEventHandlerInvoker.handle(MultiEventHandlerInvoker.java:89)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.lambda$null$1(AbstractEventProcessor.java:165)
> at
> org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:57)
> at
> org.axonframework.messaging.interceptors.CorrelationDataInterceptor.handle(CorrelationDataInterceptor.java:65)
> at
> org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:55)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.lambda$new$1(TrackingEventProcessor.java:185)
> at
> org.axonframework.messaging.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:55)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.lambda$processInUnitOfWork$2(AbstractEventProcessor.java:173)
> at
> org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:86)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.processInUnitOfWork(AbstractEventProcessor.java:159)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:462)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:294)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1016)
> at
> org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1162)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**ProducerConfig values:**

[image]
[image]

**KafkaAvroSerializerConfig values:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar error. The problem is solved when I add this properties use.latest.version=true into my config of producer-properties

Answer (score 2):

You're using `TopicNameStrategy`, so the subject name in the Registry must be `<topicName>-value`

You could also just set `auto.register.schemas=true` rather than register the schema on your own with some custom name.

Comment: i change as you mentioned but i have this error: `EventProcessor[com.test.entities.handlers]-0] | ERROR | o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener | Exception thrown when sending a message with key='e420cd3d-9e01-4e47-b94c-c2fa18c7c205' and payload='{"exerciceFrameworkId": "3a9a91d0-e547-4bc0-bcf7-34c62c43dc73", "agreementFileId": "e5d4261a-083a-44...' to topic add_bank_account: 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: User cannot access the resource; error code: 403`

Comment: Before you're getting a 404. Now you get a 403. That error is suggesting you now have ACLs that aren't allowing you to write to the topic. It's not related to the registry (or your credentials to the registry are wrong)